Counting problem involving sums
The problem states:

Select $4$ integers $a > b > c > d$ from numbers $1$ to $24$ such that $a + d = b + c$. How many ways is this possible?.

My working:

Once $a, b$, and $d$ are selected, the choice of $c$ is already determined.
The total number of ways to select $a, b, d$ is
$\displaystyle{24 \choose 3} = 2024$ ways.
In order to be able to select four distinct numbers $a, b, c$, and $d$, we must not have $b = c$ which is equivalent to the fact that $b$ is the arithmetic mean of $a$ and $d$, which means that $a$ and $d$ have the same
parity.
Hence total number of ways of selecting such a choice when $b$ is the arithmetic mean is $\binom{12}{2} = 132$.
Subtracting, $2024-132 = 1892$.

However, the given answer is half this - $946$.

@JMoravitz I have reconstructed my solution. My apologies!

Now it makes more sense and I understand the logic.  Having selected $a,b,c$ as originally written was wrong.  Having selected $a,M,d$ however is perfectly valid where $M$ is some middle number.  The division by two comes from deciding whether $M$ will refer to $b$ or whether it will refer to $c$, noting that you will have double counted... once as having selected a,b,d and again when having selected a,c,d.

This should serve as a reminder to be careful of typos.

With $\tt Mathematica$:
$$
\text{ClearAll}[a,b,c,d];\quad
\sum _{d=1}^{24} \sum _{c=1}^{24} \sum _{b=1}^{24} \sum _{a=1}^{24} \text{If}[a>b>c>d\land a+d=b+c,1,0]
$$
yields $\color{red}{\large 946}$.

With the edits, your attempt is nearly correct.  As you noted the correct answer is half of yours.
The reason why your answer is off by half is because you have double counted scenarios.  You counted once when the selection was of $\{a,b,d\}$ and you counted again when the selection was of $\{a,c,d\}$.  For instance, $(10,7,1)$ yields $10+1=7+4$ and also $(10,4,1)$ also yields $10+1=4+7$, effectively the same result.
Alternatively phrased, you failed to account for requiring that $b>c$.

Alternative approach:
Consider the following table:
\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r |}
\hline                       
\text{Range of} ~d & \text{Range of} ~a & \text{Range of} ~(a-d) & \text{Range of} ~(a-d) \\                     
& & \text{even} = 2k & \text{odd} = 2k + 1 \\
\hline                       
  1 & 4 ~:: ~24 & k=2 ~:: ~k=11 & k=1 ~:: ~k=11  \\
\hline                       
  2 & 5 ~:: ~24 & k=2 ~:: ~k=11 & k=1 ~:: ~k=10  \\
\hline                       
  3 & 6 ~:: ~24 & k=2 ~:: ~k=10 & k=1 ~:: ~k=10  \\
\hline                       
  4 & 7 ~:: ~24 & k=2 ~:: ~k=10 & k=1 ~:: ~k=9  \\
\hline
\cdots \\
\hline                       
  19 & 22 ~:: ~24 & k=2 ~:: ~k=2 & k=1 ~:: ~k=2  \\
\hline                       
  20 & 23 ~:: ~24 & k=2 ~:: ~k=2 & k=1 ~:: ~k=1  \\
\hline                       
  21 & 24 ~:: ~24 & k=1 ~:: ~k=1 & k=1 ~:: ~k=1  \\
\hline  
\end{array}
When

$(a - d)~$ is even $~ = ~2k,~$ then there are $~(k-1)~$ choices for $~(c,b).$

$(a - d)~$ is odd $~ = ~2k + 1,~$ then there are $~(k)~$ choices for $~(c,b).$


So, the desired enumeration is
$$\left\{ ~2 \times \sum_{n=2}^{11} \left[ ~\sum_{k=2}^n ~(k-1) ~\right] ~\right\} + \left\{ ~2 \times \sum_{n=1}^{10} \left[ ~\sum_{k=1}^n ~k ~\right] ~\right\} \\ + \left[  ~\sum_{k=1}^{11} ~k ~\right]. \tag1 $$
The computation in (1) above may be simplified by noting that

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^n (k-1) = \frac{n^2 - n}{2}.$

$2 \times \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{11} \frac{n^2 - n}{2} 
= \left( ~\frac{11^3}{3} + \frac{11^2}{2} + \frac{11}{6} ~\right) - ~\left( ~\frac{11^2}{2} + \frac{11}{2} ~\right)$ 
$\displaystyle = \left[ ~\frac{11^3}{3} - \frac{11}{3} ~\right] = 440.$

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n (k) = \frac{n^2 + n}{2}.$

$\displaystyle 2 \times \sum_{n=1}^{10} \frac{n^2 + n}{2} 
= \left( ~\frac{10^3}{3} + \frac{10^2}{2} + \frac{10}{6} ~\right) + ~\left( ~\frac{10^2}{2} + \frac{10}{2} ~\right)$ 
$\displaystyle = \left[ ~\frac{10^3}{3} + 10^2 + \frac{2 \times 10}{3} ~\right] = 440.$


Therefore, (1) above computes to
$$440 + 440 + 66 = 946.$$

Another alternative approach:
With $~d < c < b < a, ~$ you will have $~a + d = b + c \iff a - b = c - d.$
The problem may be construed to be a Stars and Bars problem, in disguise.  For Stars and Bars theory, see
this article and
this article.
Consider the following tableau
- - - d - - - - c - - - b - - - - a - - - - - - 

The above illustrative example positions the variables $~d, ~c, ~b, ~a~$ at positions $~4, ~9, ~13, ~18, ~$ respectively. These placements create $~5~$ islands.  Reading the islands from left to right, let $~x_1, ~x_2, ~x_3, ~x_4, ~x_5 ~$ denote the respective sizes of these islands.  So, in this example, you have that the ordered $~5$-tuple $~(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5) = (3,4,3,4,6).$
Since the variables $~d, ~c, ~b, ~a~$ occupy $~4~$ of the possible $~24~$ positions, you must have that $~x_1 + \cdots + x_5 = (24-4) = 20.$
Further, you will have $~(a - b) = (c - d) \iff x_2 = x_4.~$
So, you are looking for the enumeration of all solutions to

$x_1 + \cdots + x_5 = 20.$
$x_1, ~\cdots, ~x_5 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
$x_2 = x_4.$

From the above bullet points, you have that $~x_2 = x_4~$ must be some fixed element $~M \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,10\}.~$
For each such value of $~M,~$ the enumeration is transformed into

$~x_1 + x_3 + x_5 = (20 - 2M).$
$~x_1, ~x_3, ~x_5 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

By Stars and Bars theory, the number of solutions to the above transformed enumeration problem is
$$\binom{[20-2M] + 2}{2} = \binom{22-2M}{2} = (11 - M) \times (21 - 2M)$$
$$= 2M^2 - 43M + 231. \tag1 $$
Therefore, the desired computation is
$$\sum_{M=0}^{10} \left[ ~2M^2 - 43M + 231~\right]. \tag2 $$
Then, the computation in (2) above may be broken down, term by term.

$\displaystyle \sum_{M=0}^{10} \left[ ~2M^2 ~\right] 
= 2 \times \left[ \frac{10^3}{3} + \frac{10^2}{2} + \frac{10}{6} ~\right]$ 
$\displaystyle = \frac{2}{6} \times \left[ ~2000 + 300 + 10 ~\right] = 770.$

$\displaystyle \sum_{M=0}^{10} \left[ ~43M ~\right] 
= 43 \times \left[ \frac{10^2}{2} + \frac{10}{2} ~\right]$ 
$\displaystyle = \frac{43}{2} \times \left[ ~100 + 10 ~\right] = 2365.$

$\displaystyle \sum_{M=0}^{10} \left[ ~231 ~\right] 
= 11 \times \left[231 ~\right] = 2541.$


Therefore, the computation in (2) above is equivalent to
$$[ ~770 - 2365 ~] + 2541 = 946.$$
